# React-Native, error dissapears after I reload the app, but then appears again

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, filter, google-cloud-firestore

rececntly I encountered two really strange problems. When I am trying to load a query from cloud-firestore

```
<Text style={styles.bold}>{user.followers.includes(this.props.user.uid) ? 'UnFollow User' : 'Follow User'}</Text>
```

I get the error:
 **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.followers.indexOf')**.
But when I **delete** this line and then save the document and then immediately add the **same** line again and save, the code works how it should work, until I close my app again, and the error once again shows up.

Furthermore, I again encountered the same error caused by a line from a flatlist

```
data={this.props.messages.filter(message => message.members.indexOf(params) >= 0 && message.members.indexOf(this.props.user.uid) >= 0)}
```

The error vanishes when I remove the part `.filer(..)`
But then, similarly to the first case, it doesn't appear after I add the line again and save. 
Error: **TypeError: undefined is not an object (near'...this.props.messages.filter...')**

I think the error might be connected to loading data from firebase. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible cause would be the objects being undefined.

Your first scenario on followers :
If  user.followers is undefined and when you access the includes methods of undefined that will cause the error. When the followers array is loaded your app will work fine.
You can simply add a check like below which will show follow user till the properties are loaded or you can simply render the content after everything is loaded.

```
<Text style={styles.bold}>{user?.followers?.includes(this.props.user.uid) ? 'UnFollow User' : 'Follow User'}</Text>
```

Same would be the case for this.props.messages wherever this prop is undefined you can check if the messages has value before you filter and set the value for data which will make sure that you dont get runtime errors.

You can update the second part like below

```
data={this.props.messages && this.props.messages.filter(message => message.members.indexOf(params) >= 0 && message.members.indexOf(this.props.user.uid) >= 0)}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! How should I implement it in the second example tho? I tried
 ```data={this.props?.messages?.filter(message => message.members.indexOf(params) >= 0 && message.members.indexOf(this.props.user.uid) >= 0)} ```
But I get the error this is not a function '..._this$props$messages.filter

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting an error in the second one: **udnefined is not a function (near 'this.props.messages,filer...)**

Comment: Can you please also explain to me how the second part works? I don't really understad what is happening

Comment: is messages an array ? if its not you should use Array.isArray(this.props.messages) as the first condition

Comment: Added some description for the second part :)